# Search multiple GeoJSON feature properties in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, fields-attributes, features

I have a code to do the search function, i got the results from `var props = results[0].properties;` but `for if` not work, I don't know why.

How can I fixed and zoom to result?

This is my code:

```
    var queryInput = document.getElementById('query');
    var searchButton = document.getElementById('search');
    var resultSpan = document.getElementById('span');

function search(query) {
        resultSpan.innerHTML = 'Searching ...';
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/geoserver/vietnam/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=vietnam%3Ahtgovap&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&' + query)
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function (json) {
            var results = json.features;
            var props = results[0].properties;
            console.log(props);
            if (props && props.length > 0) {
              for (let i = 0, ii = props.length; i < ii; i++) {
                var result = props[i];
                if (result) {
                  var code = result.shthua;
                  var name = result.shbando;
                  if (
                    code &&
                    code.length > 0
                  ) {
                    setProjection(code, name);
                    return;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            setProjection(null, null);
          });
      }
    function setProjection(code, name){
        if(code == null, name == null){
            resultSpan.innerHTML = 'Không có thông tin số tờ này, thử lại...!'
            return
        }
        resultSpan.innerHTML = 'Số tờ: ' + code  +' '+ 'Diện tích: ' + name;
    }
    searchButton.onclick = function (event) {
        search(queryInput.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    };
```

This is my sample JSON from url:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"htgovap.84500","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[106.64385396,10.83672494],[106.6438059,10.83679985],[106.6438332,10.83681658],[106.6438839,10.83673733],[106.64385724,10.83671978],[106.64385396,10.83672494]]]]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"id":"HT_GOVAP.84500","soqd":"2145/QĐ-UBND","doan":"Do an dieu chinh quy hoach","shthua":93,"shbando":238,...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feature properties `props` is not an array but object, so you don't iterate through properties the same way as through array elements (see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp). You have to use `for (let variable in object)` syntax.

But since in your case you don't need all the properties, but only specific two `shthua` and `shbando`, there is not need to iterate through all the properties, you just get desired two properties. Also, since `shthua` is number, you can't check for it's length.

In your case relevant part of the code could then look like this:

```
if (props) {
  var code = props.shthua;
  if (code) {
    var name = props.shbando;
    setProjection(code, name);
  }
}
```

And for the future, this is not really a GIS related question, but pure JS one, so in the future you should post such questions on StackOverflow site.

Comment: Thanks you for the reminder. I fixed my code in your way but the result when search of  `shthua` and `shbando` are not showing in html `resultSpan.innerHTML = 'Số tờ: ' + code  +' '+ 'Diện tích: ' + name;`

Comment: I modified the code a bit, it works but only 1 result is always showing even when `queryInput` is empty and can't search data in `shthua` and `shbando`

Comment: All these are really JS questions, and as such more suitable for StackOverflow site.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and reply, sir. I will post this question to StackOverflow ♥